# Qt QSqlRelationalTableModel неверное число записей

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite3

В форме отображается всего 10 записей.

```
model = new QSqlRelationalTableModel(this, db);
model->setTable("products");
model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnFieldChange);
model->select();
```

model->rowCount() возвращает 10 записей, хотя в таблице у меня 16.

В чем может быть дело?

Comment: А какую БД Вы используете?

Comment: базу данных SQLite

Answer (score 0):

Я, конечно, могу ошибаться, но SQLite API не предоставляет отдельной функции для выполнения запроса select, там есть что-то вроде `sqlite3_exec`, которому передается коллбэк, который вызывается на каждой записи результата. Соответственно, нет и возможности *стандартным* путем узнать, сколько строк оказалось в полученном результате.

А вот что пишут в документации к исходному коду:

> If the database supports returning the size of a query (see
> QSqlDriver::hasFeature()), the number of rows of the current query is
> returned. Otherwise, returns the number of rows currently cached on
> the client.

Попробуйте в цикле вызывать [fetchMore()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html#fetchMore). Проверить, что данная операция имеет смысл можно с помощью [canFetchMore()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html#canFetchMore).

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю

Comment: сколько строк результате не особо важно пока, нужно иметь возможность нормально писать запросы